# If I define a NSString with retain, then call alloc on it, do I need to release twice? And how necessary is the self. in front of public variables?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Basic question here.

Say in my .h, I define a NSString:

```
@interface MyGreatClass
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myAwesomeString;
@end
```

And then in my .m, I have the following code:

```
@implementation MyGreatClass
@synthesize myAwesomeString
-(void)dealloc{
    [myAwesomeString release];
}
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    self.myAwesomeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Yay"];
}
@end
```

1. Did I leak? I know, I know, whenever you call `retain` or `alloc`
   on a method, it increases the counter in memory by one and you need
   to have a release statement for each `retain` and `alloc`, so I
   suspect I do, but I am just making sure because if this is true, I
   have to do this for a crapload of variables in my app. Also if you
   do have to call release twice, where do I call the second release?
   Can I call both of them in `dealloc`, one right after the other?
2. How nesesarry is the `self.` in front of variables when referring to properties of the class
   you are in? What happens if you don't have it and when exactly is it
   necesarry?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that will leak because it's overretained. The four standard correct solutions are:

```
// Solution 1:
NSString *stringToBeAwesome = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Yay"];
self.myAwesomeString = stringToBeAwesome;
[stringToBeAwesome release];

//Solution 2:
self.myAwesomeString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Yay"] autorelease];

// Solution 3:
self.myAwesomeString = [NSString stringWithString:@"Yay"];

// Solution 4:
myAwesomeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Yay"];
```

You'll notice the last one doesn't start with `self.`, which brings us to your second question. If you don't write `self.`, **you are not accessing a property**. That `myAwesomeStirng` in Solution 4 is an instance variable, accessed directly. It won't go through the property accessors, so it won't retain the value you assign and it won't release any value that the variable held before.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Is there one of these that is best, or are they all equal? Say I want to do this with a UILabel, or some other object that does not have a (for example) `stringWithString` method. Can I just use the autorelease method? It seems the easiest since I've already got a ton of alloc'd already.

Comment: @josherick: You generally want to avoid #4 except in initialization methods, because it will leak any previously assigned string. The rest are pretty much equivalent in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes. Because it's `@property (retain)`, when you set `self.myAwesomeString = ...;` it will be retained automatically. Thus, you must balance your own `alloc`.

   But keep in mind: `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Yay"]` is quite redundant. First of all, to take care of the `alloc`/`release` issue, you could use `[NSString stringWithString:@"Yay"]` which returns an autoreleased string. Furthermore, using `stringWithString:` is mostly useless unless you have a mutable string, and can be completely done away with by using `@property (copy)` instead of `@property (retain)`.

   If you're just using a constant string, you could do `self.myAwesomeString = @"Yay";`
2. When you use the `self.myAwesomeString = ...;` syntax, you're going through the setter method (it's as if you called `[self setMyAwesomeString:...];`). And when you have `@property (retain)`, this will retain the string (and release the previous value). If you just set the instance variable directly by `myAwesomeString = ...;`, you have to retain it yourself.

   Another advantage of this dot-syntax is that instead of having to call `[myAwesomeString release];` explicitly later (usually in your `-dealloc` method), you can just call `self.myAwesomeString = nil;`.

I also recommend taking a look at [ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), which will become very common in the near future, and will take care of almost all of these issues for you.

Answer (score 1):

> I know, I know, whenever you call release or alloc on a method, it
>   increases the counter in memory by one and you need to have a release
>   statement for each release and alloc ..snip..

The retain count does not increase by one when you release an object. You allocate an object using alloc, copy, or new. You increase the retain count by using retain (or copy, in cases where the value is immutable, as a NSString is). You decrease the retain count using release.

> How nesesarry is the self.

Self isn't necessary, but it's recommended, since you get some memory management for free. If you declare a property as (nonatomic, retain), the runtime makes sure that the object that is currently assigned to the underlying ivar is released before the new value is assigned, and that the new value is retained as it's assigned to the ivar.

You should always release your references when you're done with them. This is the simplest way to make sure you don't leak anything. If you adhere by this practice, you should never run into a scenario where you have to double release anything.

Comment: If I am just getting a property, not setting it, is there any reason to use `self.`?